# VBA Excel getting total number of rows with data inside ListObject

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges, listobject

I am currently working on a small project of mine, where I have a bunch of tabs and a register tab. The idea of the register tab is to set default parameters for existing tables in the other tabs and to display how much data each of the tables has ( meaning the total number of rows with data inside ). This will later be used to resize the tables and to correct the charts coming from the tables. So far I've done the following:

`findRowObject()` is just returning the row of the table in the register tab and overwriting the data in the corresponding column to actualize the current amount of rows with data. What I can't do is actually calculate the non-empty rows in the specific range of `listobject` a.k.a the table, because `lastrow` doesn't leave the correct value, possibly because my logic is incorrect. I hope the explanation was ok.

```
Sub updateCurrentDataColumn()

   Dim counter As Integer
   Dim lastRow As Integer
   Dim innerCounter As Integer
   Dim currentDataNumber As Integer
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim ob As ListObject
   Dim rangeTo As Range

   For counter = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
       If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
           counter = counter + 1
       ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
           For innerCounter = 1 To 
               ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).ListObjects.Count        
               Set ob = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).ListObjects(innerCounter)
               lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).Range(ob).End(xlUp).Rows.Count       
               Worksheets(1).Cells(findRowObject(ob.Name), 5).Value = currentDataNumber       
           Next innerCounter
       End If
   Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use `ListRows.Count`?

Comment: I've tried it already, only leaves the total number of rows within listobject, regardless of whether they are with our without data. What i need is the number of rows WITH data, i dont care for such that are empty.

Comment: Side note: use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Follow-up question: which column of the table should be used to determine what is the last filled row?

Comment: Are the empty rows continuos?

Comment: Could any *"empty"* cell contain a formula (i.e.: = if( x, y, "" )

Comment: @EEM Always the first column. The data, which is in the table, is reference to another tab. I use the "IF" formula, if no data in the other tab - leaves blank, otherwise the referenced data

Comment: @EEM The empty rows are always continous, since i am importing dynamic data from java program and can happen, that not all fields are filled with data. It has a upper range though, meaning max. number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, pass the table object and the col number to base the count from:

```
Function countNonBlankListObjectRows(t as ListObject, col as Long) as Long

   Dim totalRows as Long
   totalRows = t.ListRows.Count

   Dim blankRows as Long
   On Error Resume Next 'in case no blank rows
   blankRows = t.DataBodyRange.Columns(col).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.Count
   On Error GoTo 0

   'to include zero length cell values as blanks
   Dim zeroLength as Long
   zeroLength = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(t.DataBodyRange.Columns(col).Cells,"""")

   countNonBlankListObjectRows = totalRows - blankRows - zeroLength

End Function
```

Comment: What if there is data in other columns? What if the cell value is `""`?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to avoid the use of `ActiveWorkbook`, instead use variables `Objetcs`.

Instead of:

```
   For counter = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
       If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
           counter = counter + 1
       ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
```

Use `Object` variables

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject
```

Then do something like:

```
For Each ws In wbInput.Worksheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        With lo
```

The function `Workbook_ListObjects_Properties_ToArray`
Process the workbook `wbInput` and generates an Array `aOutput` with the required `ListObject` properties and a string message `sOutput` with any Error encountered, including when the ListObject has not Body.
It also return True if the process was successfully completed.

Note that the line function `CountIf` with the criteria `vbNullString` counts the `Empty` cells and also the cells with formulas returning the value `=""`

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, vbNullString)
```

This is the procedure:

```
Function Workbook_ListObjects_Properties_ToArray( _
    aOutput As Variant, sOutput As String, wbInput As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject, lRowsVld As Long
Dim dt As Object, aRcrd As Variant
aRcrd = Array("Workbook", "Worksheet", "ListObject", "Total.Rows", "Valid.Rows")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Rem Validate Input
    aOutput = vbNullString
    sOutput = "Input workbook is nothing"
    If wbInput Is Nothing Then GoTo Exit_Function
    sOutput = vbNullString

    Rem Set Dictionary to Collect ListObjects Properties
    Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dt.Add "Header", aRcrd

    For Each ws In wbInput.Worksheets
        For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
            With lo

                Rem Validates ListObject DataBodyRange
                If .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then

                    Rem ListObject with NO DataBodyRange
                    aRcrd = Array(wbInput.Name, ws.Name, lo.Name, "N/A", "N/A")

                Else

                    Rem Process ListObject
                    lRowsVld = .ListRows.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, vbNullString)

                    Rem Set ListObject Properties Array
                    aRcrd = Array(wbInput.Name, ws.Name, lo.Name, .ListRows.Count, lRowsVld)

                End If

                Rem Add Record to Dictionary
                dt.Add 1 + dt.Count, aRcrd

    End With: Next: Next

    Rem Set Results
    If dt.Count = 1 Then

        sOutput = "Input Workbook does not contain any ListObject"
        GoTo Exit_Function

    Else

        Rem Dictionary To Array
        aOutput = dt.items

    End If
    Workbook_ListObjects_Properties_ToArray = True

Exit_Function:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    End Function
```

It should be called like this:

```
Sub Workbook_ListObjects_ValidRows_ToArray()
Dim aLoProps As Variant
Dim sMsg As String

    If Workbook_ListObjects_Properties_ToArray(aLoProps, sMsg, ThisWorkbook) Then
        MsgBox "Post the output array!", vbInformation, "ListObjects Properties"
: Stop

    Else
        MsgBox sMsg, vbCritical, "ListObjects Properties"

    End If

    End Sub
```

[image]

Suggest to read the following pages for details about the resources used:

[Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html)
[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx)
[ListObject object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject)
[MsgBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)
[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx)
[Using Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251519.aspx)